# Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.source.FilePulseSourceConnector

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need to use kafka file pulse connector.

I have kafka (kafka_2.13-2.7.0) installed on a linux machine.

I have unzipped the zip downloaded from Git and set the connect-standalone with:

`plugin.path=/home/ec2-user/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/libs, etc/java, /home/ec2-user/kafka-connect-file-pulse-master.`

Also I have copied the jar in Kafka's lib folder (just in case) and it can´t find the class.

Finally:
`bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/quickstart-connect-file-pulse-csv.properties`

`". . . java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.source.FilePulseSourceConnector . . . "`

What is the best way to install the file pulse connector?

I only need to read text files, but now I am trying to run the quickstart csv example.

Thanks in advance. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Answer for whoever tries to install this connector:

in config/connect-standalone.properties:

plugin.path= /home/ec2-user/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/libs/,

and you have to put these jars

[list of jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Fqc.png)

kafka-connect-file-pulse-plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

kafka-connect-file-pulse-filters-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

kafka-connect-file-pulse-expression-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

kafka-connect-file-pulse-api-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Regards